# images not appear in the blade page if send it to email by using queue job Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, queue

I send an email to user for verifying, by using queue job after registration, the job run successfully but the (blade page), which sent to the user doesn't show the images, Although if I sent the blade page without send it by queue job, the images appear fine!?

**So the issue is that:**

- the images in the blade page in the user's email inbox, doesn't appear if I sent it by using the queue job, Although if I sent it directly without queue job, it appear fine.

**image'URL if I sent it by using queue job:**

http://localhost/assets/img/logo.png

[image]

**image'URL if I sent it without using queue job:**

http://localhost:8000/assets/img/logo.png

[image]

**The Blade Page**

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en"><head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('assets/css/bootstrap.css')}}">
      <style type="text/css">
      @import url({{asset('assets/css/style.css')}});

      body {

}
      </style>
    <title>login Page</title>
  </head>
<body>
<section class="row">
    <div class="col col-sm ">
    </div>
  <div class="col col-sm ml-5 pl-5" id="col1" >
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row mt-5 pl-5 mb-5 pb-5">
      <img src="{{asset('assets/img/logo.png')}}" width="80" height="80" alt=""/>
        </div>
        <div class="row mt-5 mb-5 pb-5 ">
      <img src="{{asset('assets/img/Sign in ~ Register Illustration.png')}}" width="263" height="241" alt=""/>
        </div>
        <h1>Hello,  </h1>
        <h2>Verification Code </h2>
        <div class="row mt-5 mb-5 pb-5 pr-5">
        <p class="font-style-normall font-size-18 line-spacing-33 font-family-cairo text-muted" id="text1">1Me will Keep your Contacts Secured in our Data base</p>
        </div>

      </div>

  </div>
    </section>
<script src="{{asset('js/bootstrap.js')}}"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Route:**

```
    Route::group(['middleware'=>'guest:web'], function(){
    Route::get('/register', [registerController::class,'register'])->name('site.register');
    Route::match(['get','post'],'/register-create', [registerController::class,'create'])->name('site.register.create');
});
```

**Controller:**

```
    public function create(RegisterRequest $request)
{
     $user = User::create([
        'firstName' => $request->firstName,
        'middleName' => $request->middleName,
        'lastName' => $request->lastName,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
    ]);
    $on = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->addSecond(10);
     dispatch(new VerifyEmailJob($user))->delay($on);
    return redirect()->route('landingPage')->with(['success'=>'We sent verifying email check it']);
}
```

**queue job:**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Mail\VerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class VerifyEmailJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public $user;
    public function __construct($user)
    {
        $this->user= $user;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        Mail::to($this->user->email)->send(new VerifyEmail($this->user));

    }
}
```

**Mail class:**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class VerifyEmail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public $user;

    public function __construct($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }
    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        $user = $this->user;
        return $this->subject('Mail from Oneme')
            ->view('site.auth.verifyEmail',compact('user'));
    }
}
```

Any Help

Comment: I remember having this issue when I was assigned the same task, what I ended up doing was using a cdn for my images. That way the jobs queued don't have to reference any local images instead just urls.

Comment: What if you log the value of `asset('assets/img/logo.png')` inside your job? Is it the same as when you execute it outside of a job? You can then put the path of your image in a variable before dispatching the job (if it is different). Alternatively you could indeed use a CDN or do more hacky stuff like converting your image to base64 and use `<img src=" src='data:image/png...."`

Comment: Thanks for replies, I sent the image's paths statically to the blade page like this and works but this approach isn't efficient and dynamic:

        $imgPath1 = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/img/logo.png";
        $imgPath2 = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/img/Sign%20in%20~%20Register%20Illustration.png";

        return $this->subject('Mail from Oneme')
            ->view('site.auth.verifyEmail',compact('user','imgPath1','imgPath2'));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced this issue before. For emails all path must be a Fully Qualified URL. Because queue jobs can not smartly figure out what the application's base url should be.

`https://example.com/static/logo.png` is a Fully Qualified URL, but `/static/logo.png` isn't. For this, I use a `APP_URL` env key.

When a action is being performed without http request(Like in queue system), laravel can not translate `/static/logo.png` to `https://example.com/static/logo.png`

On `.env` file I'd do something like

```
APP_URL = "https://example.com"    #change this with your application url
```

The on the view file, I'd do something like

```
<img src={{ env('APP_URL') . '/static/logo.png' }} />
```